# Input with a list of options

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically, what I want:

When I start entering the name of a city, I get a drop-down list of options that match the letters I've typed in. I want to firstly use some data which I create manually (like 10 cities with the same name, I don't really care about it for now), but I can't figure out the way to make it work - should I use both input and select and somehow hide select behind  input, or using just an input tag would be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called autocomplete and there are many tutorials online that will walk you through the process. Here are a couple:

https://www.tutsplanet.com/autocomplete-js-simple-pure-vanilla-javascript-autocomplete/

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp

You can find many others, including on YouTube.

Some considerations in choosing a tutorial: do you wish to populate the search suggestions from a back-end database, or only from a variable in javascript? If from a database, what back-end language do you want to use (PHP? Node.js?) Which database (MySQL? SQL?)

Comment: @cssphus thank you so much, I really didn't know how to name it to google it properly! For now just js, the database will be added by another person